# Run Celery task at user selected time

Tags: django, celery

I have a Django app and once a day the system should send an email at a specific time. At the moment I'm using Celery + Redis to send the email at a specific time of the day.

I want to allow the user the set the time of day that the background task must run that will send the email. What is the best way to achieve this? I can't find any examples where the user sets this time.

Alternatively I will allow the users to select the hour when the email must be sent. Either 9:00, 10:00 etc. I will then set the task to run every hour and check if any user has selected that hour. This doesn't seem like the cleanest approach. Any other suggestions?

My app is running on Heroku, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: I don't think Celery supports what you want. You probably need to implement a custom solution, for example have celerybeat run a task each minute, and in the task check which users have selected that time for sending, and send to them.

Comment: Thanks Antonis, I thought I might have to go that route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at [django-celery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery), it has Admin interface and scheduler for `celerybeat` that allows pick tasks from DB and schedule them.

So you can create some form of user interface and create [PeriodicTask](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/models.py#L209) instance.